# I need to conditionally set a field to be required

Tags: acumatica

I'm customizing the Sales Order screen as follows:

- I've added a custom boolean field added to the Order Types screen called 'Require Customer Order Number'.
- I've added code to the BLC of the Sales Order screen where I want to conditionally make the CustomerOrderNumber field required, based on whether the 'Require Customer Order Number' field is checked or not.

I'm using the SOOrder_RowSelected event as follows:

```
    protected virtual void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var soorder = (SOOrder)e.Row;
        if (soorder == null) return;

        string ordtype = soorder.OrderType;
        var soot = (SOOrderType)PXSelect<SOOrderType,
                                Where<SOOrderType.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrderType.orderType>>>>.Select(Base, ordtype);

        if (soot != null)
        {
            var sootext = PXCache<SOOrderType>.GetExtension<SOOrderTypeExt>(soot);

            if (sootext != null)
            {
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetRequired<SOOrder.customerOrderNbr>(sender, sootext.UsrRequireCustOrdNbr == null ? false : (bool)sootext.UsrRequireCustOrdNbr);
            }
        }
    }
```

This DOES put an asterisk on the CustomerOrderNumber field - but it doesn't spawn an error upon save if that field is empty.

Another issue is my PXSelect to get the record out of SOOrderType ALWAYS returns a null for the check box user field, even if it has a 'True' value in the database (which is why I put the ternary operator on the call).  Even if I hard-code a 'true' value in the PXUIFieldAttribute.SetRequired call, it still doesn't spawn the error to prevent a save.  The asterisk is there, but it doesn't work.

If I use a Cache_Attached event to add [PXDefault] it works perfectly - but this doesn't help me - I need it conditionally set.

Any ideas?

Comment: > Another issue is my PXSelect to get the record out of SOOrderType ALWAYS returns a null for the check box user field.
- Double check the DAC types, make sure they match DB and that it isn't an unbound field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required is used only for displaying the asterisk. PXDefault attribute is the one that makes the field mandatory based on PersistingCheck property value.

The issue is that PXUIFieldAttributes like PersistingCheck can only be set once at the time of graph creation. You can set it dynamically in the constructor/Initialize method but if you change the property after that it has no effects.

When I need a field to be mandatory based on a dynamic condition I remove the PXDefault attribute and validate the field manually in event handlers like RowPersisting:

```
public void PMTimeActivity_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
    PMTimeActivity timeActivity = e.Row as PMTimeActivity;

    if (timeActivity != null && PMTimeActivity.timeSpent == null)
    {
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<PMTimeActivity.timeSpent>(sender, timeActivity, "'Time Spent' cannot be empty."));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - but now I have a different problem.  No matter what I do for my RowSelected logic, I can't get the asterisk to show up on that field.  The only way is if I put the PXUIFieldAttribute.SetRequired call as the only line of code in the event.  If it's buried under ANY 'If' statements, it's as if it's ignored.  I put a  breakpoint in the code where it calls the SetRequired, it hits it - but when the screen finally renders, the asterisk isn't there.  I cannot understand it.

Comment: First of all, to keep things consistent I suggest you set values on each callback whether it's true or false, null or non null etc... If statement shouldn't be necessary. Required attribute could be one of those properties that can only be set once. To test that you can call PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled in method "public override void Initialize()" and log the value you set (true/false) in traces with PXTrace.WriteInformation. Either it changes on screen in sync with the traces or it will be stuck on the first value that was assigned.

Comment: If it's stuck on the first value assigned you can't set that property dynamically and you'll have to choose between always showing the asterisk and always hiding it.